# Measure upon which pointwise convergence of averaging operator fails in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

If $\mu$ is a doubling Radon measure on $\mathbf{R}^n$, it is well known that for any locally integrable function $f$, the values

$$ (A_\delta f)(x) = \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,\delta))} \int_{B(x,\delta)} f(t) d\mu(t)  $$

converges pointwise $\mu$ almost everywhere to $f(x)$. Are there any simple examples of non doubling absolutely continuous measures $\mu$ where this phenomenon fails to occur?